# Trying to Run SQL Stored Procedure in EXCEL Automatically

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, t-sql, vba

The below query requires me to manually Set the `@begin_date` and `@end_date` manually, then i copy and paste into SQL and Execute.

```
Use Analytical                                                                                      

Declare @end_date       DATE
,@begin_date        DATE                                                                                        

Set     @begin_date = '11/20/2017'
Set     @end_date = '11/26/2017'    

If Object_ID('Temp_Table_1') is not null
Drop Table Temp_Table_1
```

The first two temp tables are pulls to get all of the information in correctly, `ALSTMF` and `ALCOVR` must both be updated for the table to work!

My goal however is to be able to use a syntax that will generate the date range automatically and give me the same result. so i tried using 'GETDATE' on the same query and it did not generate any result.

```
Use Analytical                                                                                  
Declare @end_date       DATE
,@begin_date        DATE

SELECT GETDATE() - 7

If Object_ID('Temp_Table_1') is not null
Drop Table Temp_Table_1
```

When i ran this query, with other parts of the query, no records was generated. Can anyone please advice me on what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Declare
@end_date DATE
, @begin_date DATE

Set @begin_date = '20171120'
Set @end_date = '20171112'

--the date depend of your laguange, try YYYYmmdd

If Object_ID('Temp_Table_1') is not null
Drop Table Temp_Table_1